# Organizer badge not awarded after a retag

Tags: support, tags, badges, edit-badges

Yesterday, I added one tag to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148550/does-a-begin-end-block-affect-the-performance-of-a-conditional-statement) question, but I didn't get the Organizer badge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After looking at your question and account, I think you have misunderstood what the organizer badge is.

It is for re-tagging **other** people's posts, not your own.  This can be done after you've reached 500 rep.

Comment: Sorry for my silly mistake.. I waited for more than 12 hours.. still I am not having organizer badge.

Comment: @Himadri -- Sorry, I didn't look carefully at the time stamp.  I was just thinking that, yes, I noticed a delay between when I first re-tagged and when I got my badge.  I've offered an alternative (and one which I believe to be correct) suggestion to your problem in my answer.

Comment: OK thanks for that... but in help of organizer badge it is just written `First Retag`. That's why I misunderstood.

Comment: @Himadri I read over the badge, and I do agree that it's a bit misleading.  Perhaps you could offer a feature request?