# Please improve the description of the Organizer badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-description

After I read the description of the `Organizer` badge, I thought it was awarded for re-tagging any question.  But when I retagged my own post, I didn't get an `Organizer` badge.  So, I asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/retag-but-didnt-get-an-organizer-badge) question, and learned that the badge is only awarded for retagging *another* user's post.

I propose updating the description for the `Organizer` badge so that future new users don't have this problem.

Comment: This still hasn't been changed. It totally confused me, too. Thanks to Google I now know what `Organizer` really is!

Comment: i had the same problem until i looked for recent people who get this badge and found the answer .but what is the reputation requirment for retaging

Comment: This is just the sort of problem that the [enhanced badge list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) is supposed to solve.</shamelessPlug>

Answer (score 5):

Not just Organizer... there are more badges which are not properly described properly like:

- Copy Editor - Edited 600 entries (What kind of entries? eg. questions, answers, comments or all of them?)
- Civic Duty - Voted 300 or more times (People have voted me 300 times or I have voted others 300 times?)
- and others...

I'm sorry if many people see these as straightforward, but I was unable to understand some badge meanings.

Comment: The descriptions are now "Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)" and "Vote 300 or more times". The former is as obvious as it's going to get. The latter is only slightly changed from the original wording but may be slightly more clear than before.