# What exactly is the Organizer badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please improve the description of the Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/please-improve-the-description-of-the-organizer-badge)

What exactly is the Organizer badge?

Answer (score 2):

You get this badge for retagging a question (editing the tags). You can only get it once, and only for retagging a question that you have not asked yourself.

Both binding, privileged edits and suggested edits also count towards this badge.

Comment: Hmm.I still dont get it.But its OK.Just curious

Comment: @Mithun: ah, that's probably because I haven't made it very clear that *you can't see the "retag" link at all* if you don't have enough rep to use it.

Comment: 23 is certainly no enough then ;-)

Comment: @Mithun: yep, as I said, you'll need at least 200 points (or 500 on SOFU).

Comment: They really need to clarify in the badge's description that it has to be done on somebody else's question.