# What is 'Retag' for the organizer badge?

Tags: support, tags, badges

**The question is *NOT* about the organizer badge, but about what *retag* means.**

I was checking what the organizer badge is and noticed there is not a description of what 'retag' exactly means or how it's done.

Checking [Organizer badge not awarded after a retag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55546/organizer-badge-not-awarded-after-a-retag), it says that the badge is warded for re-tagging other people's posts.  And there are still 2 related questions: [What exactly is the Organizer badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65911/what-exactly-is-the-organizer-badge) and [Please improve the description of the Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/please-improve-the-description-of-the-organizer-badge)

But there is still no information about what retag means. Not even in the help https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Retagging by dictionary definitions doesnt help (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retag), much less when applied to this specific context ( Much less for non native speakers) .

So, does retag in this context means to duplicate accidentally an existing tag when proposing one?, to edit one badly written already created tag? or what exactly?

Comment: @Anne Daunted GoFundMonica Is there any document where it tells you that?.. and can you put your answer as an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: I've also filed [another feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311669/change-description-of-organizer-badge-to-be-more-descriptive) to make the description less confusing.

Comment: Well, more than a request for  describing better what the badge is this is about defining what 'retag' means. But yeah, if the badge was better described the answer to this question would be easier to find.

Comment: See also: [What are the Badges - Organizer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/282094) and [What should we do with the Organizer badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311672/282094)

Comment: @Rob Thank you as those do help´. But the question is not about the organizer badge.

Comment: deags, your question asks about retagging and the Organizer badge explains it: "... Edit the tags on a question asked by another user, Your own questions don't count, Both binding, privileged edits and suggested edits count for the badge (once approved), ..., etc.".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)

Comment: @Rob I'm moving to leave this open since the information wasn't in that post until after this question was asked.

Comment: @Sonic that's not a reasonable course of action or a valid reason, but it's your review history and risk of a ban for a review failure. I see some of the other comments were trimmed and that people don't understand that some of the comments that are posted are automatically added or removed by the software - usually you aren't one of those but instead one whom ensures that the FAQs are clear and things are in order, othertimes not so much.

Comment: @Rob I once used to edit in information into FAQs in response to new questions, then later close them as duplicates, but I was later told not to do that and that such questions should be left open. Also, the intent behind the reply markup was more to publicly indicate to others that my comment was a reply to the duplicate proposal; the fact that it notifies you was entirely incidental in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was found among the comments in various questions and not in  documentation, but basically, *retag*  means that you go into a post and change/ edit the tags that question has.

For the context of the badge of *'Organizer'* its exactly that but adding the condition that you need to edit the tags on a post made by a person different than yourself.

The badge was mentioned because that is the context on where the questioning happened.