# Change description of Organizer badge to be more descriptive

Tags: feature-request, badges, wording, edit-badges

This is not a duplicate of [Please improve the description of the Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/please-improve-the-description-of-the-organizer-badge), as that asks to make it more clear that it doesn't apply to one's own questions; my request is totally different.

Ever since the former [retag privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158913/why-do-we-have-the-retag-privilege) (which allowed 500+ rep users to make tag edits without needing to have them approved as suggested edits) was removed, the word "retag" is pretty much not used in the software

...except in the short description of the Organizer badge, which is "First retag". This is not at all clear, because the word "retag" is only mentioned [once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) in the help center, on a totally unrelated page, and the word is only defined in [an unrelated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions). This has caused users to [get confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311668/a-retag-an-organizer-badge?noredirect=1).

Can we change the short description of the badge to "First tag edit"?

Per [Shog's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311702/377214) and evidence from recently awarded badges, animuson's comment below that the badge is only awarded for tag-only edits is **incorrect**; the badge *is* awarded for tag edits that also modify the title or body.

Comment: I Agree! But don't you think changing it to also state on another users post like they said here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/please-improve-the-description-of-the-organizer-badge
It could be "First tag edit to another users post"

Comment: Tbh I'd rather just get rid of the badge than waste time trying to make the description clearer. Your suggestion doesn't really clarify things, because it's only awarded on a tag-*only* edit. With the privilege gone, this is just a really dumb badge that does exactly the same thing as Editor just with an additional restriction. Like the retag privilege itself, it no longer serves any purpose. We shouldn't be encouraging users to *only* edit the tags when on the edit screen.

Comment: @animuson Organizer is one of the 20 badges that count toward moderator candidate scores in elections. What should we put in its place?

Comment: @animuson Like Sonic said, "What should we put in its place?" There would have to be some kind of replacement for the badge.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Literally any other bronze badge not already included would be just as useful in the score. Maybe Excavator?

Comment: @animuson see: [What should we do with the Organizer badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311672/what-should-we-do-with-the-organizer-badge)

Comment: @animuson I just got an [Organizer badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/5/organizer?userid=69714) for an [edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/98707) which also changed the body; this seems to contradict your statement about tag-only edits. Or has this behaviour changed in the meantime?

Comment: @itstoobadilostmymainaccount Per another employee's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311702/377214) and evidence from recently awarded badges, animuson's comment above was wrong; it looks like the Organizer badge is here to stay.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog True but the description could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "First tag edit on somebody else's question". That doesn't only solve the problem described in this question, but it also makes it clear that retags on your own questions don't count, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55546/349538) (to make sure that that's still the case, I tested retagging [my own question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11986/513819) on a site where I don't have an Organizer badge and I still haven't gotten the badge).

Otherwise, "Edit tags on somebody else's question for the first time" might make it even more clear, since some new users might think that "tag edit" means "tag-only edit" or "tag wiki edit" (when I was a new user I thought that "tag edit" meant "tag wiki edit"). Note that the Organizer badge is also awarded for edits that edit both the tags and other parts of the question as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1018824), so it might be a good idea to make it clear that the badge isn't only awarded for tag-only edits.

Comment: "First tag edit on another person's question" would be better, as a couple of the other badges use the phrase "another person's question"